# Unable to copy value from webpage

Tags: python, request

I would like to get the value `387` from the page `https://house.leju.com/dl147961/`.

```
res = requests.get('https://house.leju.com/dl147961/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
num = soup.find('h2', {'class':'clearfix'}).find('em', {'class':'new_font'}).text
```

Surprisingly, `num` is `628`!

Even just copying and the value in browser, the result is `628`.

What is the correct way to do it?

Figure : [image]

Comment: If my answer was helpful please mark it as correct and/or upvote it :)

Comment: Please add other sites you wish to include or ask another question with all the sites listed as it is near impossible to come up with a method that would apply universally across all possibile configurations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is beacuse they use non standard font which use characters numbers. If you inspect the site you will see that in fact it is 628:

`<em class="new_font">628</em>`
But if you look at the definition of `new_class` you will see that it maps characters:

```
.new_font {
    font-family: "new_font","\5fae\8f6f\96c5\9ed1",Microsoft JhengHei,"\534e\6587\7ec6\9ed1",STHeiti,MingLiu,Serif!important;
}
```

Sot the value 628 just means character index 6 which equals 3, character index 2 which equals 8 and so on. So you would need to import this font into python and then get real value by using its index the same way you can refer to ASCII characters by their number. Alternatively you can create a quick and dirty map on your own. Just right click inspect and use chrome developers tools to dynamically change the value of `em` tag to see what values it will show as I did. Bellow the mapping:

`1234567890 = 9802431765`

On the left the single digit you will get from requests on the right the way it appears on the site. So you need to split the number into individual digits and convert each one according to the map given by me.

So 628:

```
6->3
2->8
8->7
```

Full working example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mapping ={
    "1":"9",
    "2":"8",
    "3":"0",
    "4":"2",
    "5":"4",
    "6":"3",
    "7":"1",
    "8":"7",
    "9":"6",
    "0":"5"
}
res = requests.get('https://house.leju.com/dl147961/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
num = soup.find('h2', {'class':'clearfix'}).find('em', {'class':'new_font'}).text

result = ''
for d in num:
    result += mapping[d]

print(result)
```

Comment: @QHarr I used chrome developers tools and dynamically  changed the value of `em` tag to see what values it will show.

Comment: I found that the mapping of digits is not unique. Any other better way?

Comment: @Chan what do you mean by not unqiue?

Comment: I mean `3` maps to `0` this time but in other pages, it may map to `4`.

Comment: You mentioned that we may import font into python and then get real value by using its index the same way you can refer to ASCII characters by their number. How to do that?

Comment: @Chan well that means different font was used. As mentioned this was quick way targeting a single font. The other way which I mentioned first is that you need to get the font of the element install it and then decode the character no other way around it.

Comment: @Chan The other method is not so easy as the font can be applied in diffrent ways so the implementation of the method will vary from site to site.

Comment: @Chan in my opinion I answered your question if the method was supposed to be applied to a range of sites they should have been listed in the question

Comment: What are the actual characters do "\5fae\8f6f\96c5\9ed1" and "\534e\6587\7ec6\9ed1" represent?

Comment: @Chan Those values represent custom font name as far as I am aware. They look like byte values so probably this is due to encoding. My best guess is that those after decoding represent font name in Chinese characters.

Comment: @Chan Decoding the first values as utf-16 gives `微软雅黑` I am not sure if this does make sense.